# Laravel if statement for various numbered items to change styles

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I have a gallery of products laid out like this:

[image: gallery of products]

```
<div class="row no-gutters bg-light">
                @foreach ($products as $product)
                <!-- Column 1 -->
                <div class="col-6 @if(count($products) === 1 || 4 || 5) card-w-bg @endif">
                    <div class="row no-gutters">
                        <!-- Column 1-a --> 
                        <div class="col-6 showcase-col">
                            <div class="overlay"></div>
                            <div class="showcase-hero showcase-text">
                                <h2 class="card-title mb-4"><a href="">{{ $product->name }}</a></h2>
                                <h3 class="card-subtitle text-muted">{{ $product->details }}</h3>
                                <h4 class="mb-3">{{ $product->presentPrice() }}</h4>
                                <p class="card-text mb-4 d-none d-md-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A
```

The if statement needs to add the dark gray bg to items 1, 4 and 5 only.

Comment: 1, 4 and 5 are the products ids?

Comment: No theyre not the ids, they're the number of the column for the looped item to display in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1,4 and 5 are the products ids you can:

```
@if($product->id === 1 || $product->id === 4 || $product->id === 5) card-w-bg @endif
```

If 1,4 and 5 are the place in the loop:

```
@if($loop->iteration === 1 || $loop->iteration === 4 || $loop->iteration === 5) card-w-bg @endif
```

Comment: Yes, used $loop->iteration, works perfectly, thanks porloscerros

Answer (score 0):

The way you have applied if condition is wrong, correct way is showb below:

```
@if(count($products) == 1 || count($products) == 4 || count($products) == 5) //change over here
//some code 
@endif
```

Therefore, replace

```
 <div class="col-6 @if(count($products) === 1 || 4 || 5) card-w-bg @endif">
```

to the following:

```
<?php $reqArr=[1,4,5]; ?>
<div class="col-6 @if(in_array(count($products),$reqArr)) card-w-bg @endif">
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to use the [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) created by laravel's foreach so you can access the current index instead of using `count` on `$products` that will always return the same value. So you can do something like this:

```
<div class="col-6 {{ $loop->index == 0 || 3 || 4 ? 'card-w-bg' : ''}}">
```